# URL rewriting not working in apache2/ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, url-rewriting, apache2

I need to redirect my request from one url (/var/www/imgservice/test.php) to another URL (/A/B/C) where A,B and C are folders.
I am currently on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and my DocumentRoot is /var/www/
I am trying to use the rewrite_mod in apache2 to make the redirect possible.

For that i have done the following:

1) In apache2.conf i have added this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule /  /var/www/test.php
</IfModule>
```

2) At /etc/apache2/sites-available in default file i have added the following

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
```

3) Then i ran this command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

4) Then i restarted the server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now when i go on the URL and type XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/ i still see my index.html page and not the php while which was redirected.

This setup works good on my local windows machine.

What i am missing here? Can anyone help it will be great help

thanks

Mayank

Comment: try deleting index.html ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I deleted the index.html but i can only see the directory structure now after Index of /

Comment: i think there is a problem about redirecting.

Comment: So is there any way i can get this working. Meaning some cleanups, system restarts, adding deleting files something..

Comment: Problem solved using Regex in RewriteRule